# pegar valor espcefico de um texto do tipo string [PYTHON]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estou tentando pegar o valor especifico de um retorno que fiz usando requests

O python retornou todo o HTML do site no print(return.text), mas eu quero pegar somente esse input:

```html
<input class="give-input required" type="text" name="descricao" autocomplete="given-name" placeholder="First Name" id="descricao" value="Roberta Bellamy" required="" aria-required="true">
```

Sou novo no python!

Comment: Aqui está o input que quero atribuir uma variavel a ele: <input class="give-input required" type="text" name="descricao" autocomplete="given-name" placeholder="First Name" id="descricao" value="Roberta Bellamy" required="" aria-required="true">

Comment: Seja Bem Vindo ao SOpt, recomendo dar uma passada pelo nosso [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), e ler um pouco sobre o [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável para criar perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Da maneira que está, o código não pode ser reproduzido e testado. O que você já conseguiu fazer?

Comment: Mas independentemente do que seja o HMTL completo e o seu código, acredito que você possa usar [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), [manipulação de strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) ou até a biblioteca [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Answer (score 3):

Mesmo que não tenha posto informação suficiente, vou demonstrar como é fácil fazer isso com o [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

O BeautifulSoup é uma biblioteca focada em webscrapping, na busca de dados em HTML e XML. A utilização é simples. No caso, depois de instalar (`pip install bs4`), você importa no bs4 a classe principal BeautifulSoup e a instancie com um html e um parser de preferência (como [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) ou o [lxml](https://lxml.de/)).

Para encontrar uma tag específica, indique o número mínimo de informações para achar aquela única tag ao invés de várias do mesmo tipo.

Traduzindo para um código pronto seria:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

textoHTML = '<html><head></head><body><input aria-required="true" autocomplete="given-name" class="give-input required" id="descricao" name="descricao" placeholder="First Name" required="" type="text" value="Roberta Bellamy"/></body></html>' #SEU HTML ARQUI

soup = BeautifulSoup(textoHTML, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find("input", class_=['given-input', 'required'], id='descricao'))
# IMPRIME: <input aria-required="true" autocomplete="given-name" class="give-input required" id="descricao" name="descricao" placeholder="First Name" required="" type="text" value="Roberta Bellamy"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `replace` para remover as `tags` desta forma:

```
linha1 = "<p>Conceito <span>e</span> <span>Signi</span>ficado<span> </span>de <span>Tex</span>to.</p>"
linha2 = "<p><span>Geralmente</span>, entendemos <span>o</span> texto como um <span>conjunto</span> de frases</p>"

linha1 = linha1.replace('<span>','').replace('</span>','')
linha2 = linha2.replace('<span>','').replace('</span>','')

print(linha1)
print(linha2)
```

Saída:

```
<p>Conceito e Significado de Texto.</p>
<p>Geralmente, entendemos o texto como um conjunto de frases</p>
```

Comment: Se quiser remover também as `tags` de parágrafo poderia fazer desta forma: `linha1.replace('<span>','').replace('</span>','').replace('<p>','').replace('</p>','')`